Adding position to an element which is inside a 'flexbox' - independently
I need to drag the blue rectangle to the left so that it becomes visible to users.
I tried making it 'position: relative' and it let me change its position with 'left: 40px' - but then it completely destroyed the display of the page.
Is that even possible to change an element's position while inside a flexbox?
Thank you.


var left = document.getElementById('drag-left');
var right = document.getElementById('drag-right');
var bar = document.getElementById('dragbar');

const drag = (e) => {

  document.selection ? document.selection.empty() : window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  left.style.width = (e.pageX - bar.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
}

bar.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
});

bar.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.drag-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

[class^="panel"] {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.panel-one {
  width: 44.6%;
}

.panel-two {
  flex: 1;
  width: 56.4%;
}

.dragbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(25, 0, 75);
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
<div class="drag-container">
  <div class="panel-one" ; id="drag-left">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/nvhgVgPN.png" ; style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <h1 style="text-decoration: underline;">Safkfsdf Akslefos Alpsdfd</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ullam reprehenderit modi eius numquam.Quia saepe nulla aliquid nesciunt et a pariatur expedita mollitia. Suscipit necessitatibus temporibus architecto ea rerum eveniet. Vitae quis sint tenetur
      impedit corrupti esse error amet minima enim. Eos quas similique aperiam itaque autem. Veritatis optio deleniti, deserunt animi soluta, nam ab aut maxime inventore quis voluptate. Ipsam, corporis earum. Ipsa quasi ipsum eius, dolor dolore assumenda!
      Eum quod fugit iste dignissimos exercitationem libero, numquam reprehenderit, rerum totam, delectus expedita voluptas nam unde! Magnam corrupti ratione amet. Quaerat quasi qui pariatur earum nobis velit, nemo consectetur laborum tenetur sed! Modi
      ipsa temporibus mollitia dolor inventore. Sapiente molestias alias nesciunt! Dolor non quas soluta eaque repellendus enim ipsam.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="dragbar" ; id="dragbar">
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-two" ; id="drag-right">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/t3LSZHyf.png" ; width="214%" ; height="100%">
  </div>
</div>



Thank you

Dragging the dark blue vertical bar in your snippet seems to work absolutely fine to me. Can you please give additional details about what you expect to happen, and what 'completely destroyed the display' actually means.

Sure! Thanks! The problem is I need the 'Main Article' (hidden in the very right of the right panel) to move left to fit the panel. When applying 'position: relative' to the screenshot (to be able to move it) - it's not longer a part of the container so it makes all elements get messed up on the screen, Thank you!! @RoryMcCrossan

Because basically my problem is when I changed the screenshot example img's 'width' (seen in the html of the full code) from '100%' to '140%' I needed it to expand to the opposite direction - so that it'd display properly @RoryMcCrossan

Sorry, @user25017272, even with these additional comments I still don’t have a clear picture of the difference between how your snippet behaves and how you want it to behave. Please edit your post to include some screenshots and/or mockups which clearly illustrate both the problem and the desired result.
